# PHP error when adding swf game file

Tags: php, flash

I have an adult tube site setup using AVS.

I tried to add a game (swf file), but after uploading is complete, it shows an error "Please selected a game file!" even though I have selected one.

Any idea what might be happening here?  THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The file was being rejected because the max file upload in php was set to just 2M.
I changed it's value in my php config and now file uploads work great!